# To what extent is it possible to generalise a natural bijection between trees and $7$-tuples of trees, suggested by divergent series?

Tags: combinatorics, divergent-series

In the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9405205v1.pdf) "Seven Trees In One" by Andreas Blass, a "very explicit" bijection is found between [trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) and 7-tuples of such trees.

The idea to construct such a bijection stems from looking at some particular divergent series, as mentioned in Chapter 2 of the paper:

> To see why seven is special, we ﬁrst give an argument to establish Theorem 1
>   in the style of eighteenth-century analysis, where meaningless computations (e.g.,
>   manipulating divergent series as though they converged absolutely and uniformly)
>   somehow gave correct results. This argument begins with the observation that a
>   tree either is 0 or splits naturally into two subtrees (by removing the root). Thus
>   the set T of trees satisﬁes $T = 1 + T^
> 2$
>   . (Of course equality here actually means
>   an obvious isomorphism. Note that the same equation holds also for the variant
>   notions of tree mentioned at the end of Section 1.) Solving this quadratic equation
>   for T, we ﬁnd $T =
> 1/2
>  ± i \sqrt{3}/2 $
>   . (The reader who objects that this is nonsense has
>   not truly entered into the eighteenth-century spirit.) These complex numbers are
>   primitive sixth roots of unity, so we have $T^
> 6 = 1$ and $T^
> 7 = T$. And this is why
>   seven-tuples of trees can be coded as single trees.

A more elaborate explanation can be found [here](http://www.thebigquestions.com/2013/05/09/seven-trees-in-one/).

Mr. Blass does not elaborate a lot on the divergent series he mentioned. This is explained in a bit more detail in a blog [post](http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/sum-divergent-series-ii/) on the "Everything Seminar". The divergent sum of the Catalan numbers (where the $n$'th Catalan number is defined as $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n} $) is computed by looking at the corresponding [generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) of these numbers: $$ T(z) =  1 + z + 2z^2 + 5z^3 + 14z^4 + 42z^5 + \dots $$

It is mentioned in that blog post that the coefficient of $x^n$ is the number of binary rooted trees with $n+1$ leaves. Combining these pieces of information, it can be computed that $$T(z) = \frac{1- \sqrt{1-4z}}{2z} .  $$

By plugging in $x=1$, we obtain that $$ 1 + 1 + 2 + 5 + 14 + 42 + \dots "=" \frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = e^{-\pi i/3} . $$

Therefore, we "know" that $$ 1 + 1 + 2 + 5 + 14 + 42 + \dots "=" (1 + z + 2 + 5 + 14 + 42 + \dots)^7 $$

This suggested the bijection in the paper by Blass. I am curious, though, whether there are more instances of divergent series that suggest bijections between certain combinatorial objects. For instance, we also have the Fibonacci generating function $$ F(z) = 1 + z + 2z^2 + 3z^3 + 5z^4 + 8z^5 + \dots = \frac{z}{1-z-z^2} .  $$ (Here, the $n$'th coefficient is defined as $f_{n} = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2} $, where $f_0 = f_1 = 1$.)

If we let $z$ go to $1$, we find that $$ 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + \dots "=" -1 .$$

Therefore, we find that $$ 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + \dots "=" (1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + \dots)^{2k+1} \qquad (1), $$ is true as well, for integer $k > 0 $ .

**Question 1**: Does this "equality" (1) involving the Fibonacci divergent series admit a combinatorial interpretation as well? Can a bijection between combinatorial structures similar to the one mentioned in Blass' paper be constructed based on this interpretation as well?

Furthermore, we can compute that $$ 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + \dots = -1 $$ by means of a generating function as well. (Here, the $n$'th term is of the form $2^n$.) So we have $$ 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + \dots = (1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + \dots)^{2k+1} \qquad (2)  $$ for integer $k>0$ as well.

**Question 2**: Does equality (2) admit a combinatorial interpretation and a corresponding "very explicit" bijection as well?

**Question 3**: If there are combinatorial interpretations of equalities (1) and (2), could there exist "very explicit" bijections between these different combinatorial structures too?

Comment: http://fr.arxiv.org/abs/math/0004133 it doesn't answer your question or come close, but maybe it's related. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species

Comment: @johnmangual thank you!

Comment: @Alex J Best: thanks a lot for the bounty!

Comment: @MaxMuller No problem, shame it doesn't seem to have worked so well!

Comment: I've asked the same question on MO some years ago. It has an interesting answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168913/to-what-extent-is-it-possible-to-generalise-a-natural-bijection-between-trees-an