# How to generalize "Seven trees in one" to labelled/colored trees?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, category-theory, computer-science

In the famous paper [Seven trees in one](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9405205v1.pdf), [Andreas Blass](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/48510/andreas-blass) showed that there is "a particularly elementary bijection between the set $T$ of finite binary trees and the set $T^7$ of seven-tuples of such trees".

For the Haskellers, if we define

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node Tree Tree
```

this leads to a bijection of types

```
iso :: Tree -> (Tree, Tree, Tree, Tree, Tree, Tree, Tree)
```

The justification, which [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212377) elaborates on, stems from the fact that for the set $T$ of trees, the recursive definitions yields an isomorphism $$T \cong T^2 + 1.$$ Treating this as an *equation of complex numbers*, we'd get

$$T = \frac 1 2 \pm \frac 1 2 i \sqrt 3$$

which is a primitive sixth root of unity, thus yielding $T^7 = T$.

This fascinating isomorphism just works for trees with no information attached to the nodes, as it just operates on the structure of the tree. I would love to see how we could incorporate actual, labelled nodes though (or better: colored nodes, see comments below). What do we get if we introduced labels on the nodes (with one of $n$ possibilities)? Say

```
data Label = A1 | ... | An
data Tree = Leaf | Node Label Tree Tree
```

Now we have an isomorphism $$T \cong 1 + nT^2$$ with complex solution
$$T = \frac 1{2n}(1+i\sqrt{4n-1}).$$

E.g. for $n=2$ we had

$$T = \frac 1 4 (1 \pm i\sqrt 7).$$

None of these solutions can be roots of unity for $k>1$ because of their absolute values, so some nontrivial isomorphism $T^k \cong T^\ell$ won't arise. Are there other results one can achieve?

I know that this question basically amounts to asking if there is nice integral polynomial equation satisfied by the complex value for $T$ above, which means nice polynomial multiples of $nT^2-T+1$. Has there been any work done on these?

Thank you for your comments

---

I know [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817011/), though it's way broader (and hasn't received an answer anyway).

Comment: It seems to me your definition of "labelled" trees misses the mark in a couple of respects.  For one thing the leaves are not labelled.  Second the labels are not uniquely assigned to nodes.  The definition given resembles more closely an $n$-*coloring* of nodes (apart from leaf nodes).

Comment: Thanks for the remark regarding terminology, then coloring seems to be what I was thinking of. The leaves don't matter, as you can identify a `c`-colored leaf with a `Node c Leaf Leaf`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.129.2549&rep=rep1&type=pdf). It gives some results for lists, naturals, and constants as well.

Comment: link is dead unfortunately, I think it may have been to [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/964001.964008) that cites Blass's trees paper.